# Using complete induction, prove that if $a_1=2$, $a_2=4$, and $a_{n+2}=5a_{n+1}-6a_n$, then $a_n=2^n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, induction

Could anyone please explain to me how to do this problem by using the principle of complete induction? Thanks. :)

> Let $a_1=2$, $a_2=4$, and $a_{n+2}=5a_{n+1}-6a_n$ for all $n\geq 1$. Prove that $a_n=2^n$ for all natural numbers $n$.

Comment: what did you try? where are you getting stuck?

Comment: @IttayWeiss I just don't understand how to proceed when you need to implement the n=k or n= k+1 for this type of induction. That's why I'm asking for guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For induction we wish to show the following:

1. If $a_{n+2} = 2^{n+2}$ and $a_{n+1} = 2^{n+1}$ for some particular positive integer $n$ then: $a_{n+3} = 2^{n+3}$ must be true for that same value $n$
2. $a_1 = 2^1$ and $a_2 = 2^2$

Since if 1 is true and 2 is true then we can repeatedly use 1 from the truth of 2 to establish that

1. $a_n = 2^n$ for all $n >= 1$

Proving point number 2 is trivial. It is already given to us. We now must prove point number 1.

1. Assume that

$$a_{n+2} = 2^{n+2}$$

$$a_{n+1} = 2^{n+1}$$

For some arbitrary positive integer n.

1. Notice that using the original definition:

$$a_{n+3} = 5*a_{n+2} - 6*a_{n+1} = 5*2^{n+2} - 6*2^{n+1}$$

Now we will simplify this expression:

$$5*2^{n+2} - 6*2^{n+1} =2*(5*2^{n+1})- (5*2^{n+1}) - 2^{n+1}$$

We now factor and reorganize:

$$2*(5*2^{n+1})- (5*2^{n+1}) - 2^{n+1} =(5*2^{n+1})(2 - 1) - 2^{n+1} = (5*2^{n+1}) - 2^{n+1} $$

And now simplify:

$$ (5*2^{n+1}) - 2^{n+1} = 4*2^{n+1} = 2*2^{n+2} = 2^{n+3} $$

Thus we have shown: that if

$$a_{n+2} = 2^{n+2}$$

$$a_{n+1} = 2^{n+1}$$

and

$$a_{n+3} = 5*a_{n+2} - 6*a_{n+1}$$

Then:

$$a_{n+3} = 2^{n+3}$$

Thus we are now done with the induction.

Comment: Thanks a lot. your walk-through the problem was pretty good. I think I now got the hang of it. :)

Comment: There seems to be some superfluous work there:$$5\cdot2^{n+2}-6\cdot2^{n+1}=5\cdot2^{n+2}-3\cdot2^{n+2}=2\cdot2^{n+2}=2^{n+3}$$

Comment: I'm just making clear exactly whats going on. Its better to be thorough with a user of unknown skill level than to leave out a step that could make an otherwise good explanation inaccesible.

Answer (score 10):

It’s pretty straightforward; you really need only follow the models that you’ve already seen. Your induction hypothesis will be that $a_k=2^k$ for $k=1,2,\dots,n$, where $n$ is any integer greater than $2$, and your induction step will then be

$$\begin{align*}
a_{n+1}&=5a_n-6a_{n-1}&&\text{by the given recurrence}\\
&=5\cdot2^n-6\cdot2^{n-1}&&\text{by the induction hypothesis}\\
&=5\cdot2\cdot2^{n-1}-6\cdot2^{n-1}&&\text{to get a common factor}\\
&=(10-6)2^{n-1}&&\text{pulling out the common factor}\\
&=\ldots
\end{align*}$$

Can you finish the calculation?

Comment: Hey nice seeing you again, man. Before, I finish the calculations, shouldn't the first line be $a_{k+2}=5a_{k+1}-6a_{k}$.

Comment: @Kurusugi: No, because my induction hypothesis is that $a_k=2^k$ for all $k\le n$, and I’m trying to prove that it’s true for the next value of $k$ after all of these. Note that $$a_{k+2}=5a_{k+1}-6a_k\quad\text{for all}\quad k\ge 1$$ and $$a_{n+1}=5a_n-6a_{n-1}\quad\text{for all}\quad n\ge 2$$ and for that matter $$a_{k+15}=5a_{k+14}-6a_{k+13}\quad\text{for all}\quad k\ge-12$$ all say exactly the same thing: that starting with the third term of the sequence, each term is $5$ times the previous one minus $6$ times the one before that.

Comment: Thanks, I think I now get it. By the way, The answers comes out to be $2^{n-3}$ based on your calculations.. :D

Comment: @Kururugi: You’re welcome. (It can take a little while to get used to the fact that what’s important in these recurrences is the **relationships** among the subscripts, not the specific indexing chosen.)

Answer (score 1):

We give a slightly odd solution that you are probably not intended to use, but it may be informative.  Let $b_n=2^n$. It is clear that the sequence $(b_n)$ satisfies the initial conditions $a_1=2$ and $b_2=4$. We can also verify that $b_{n+2}=5b_{n+1}-6b_{n}$ for all $n \ge 3$. For $$5b_{n+1}-6b_n=5\cdot 2^{n+1}-6\cdot 2^n=2^n[10-6]=2^{n+2}=b_{n+2}.$$

Now all we need is the following result.

**Lemma:** Suppose that two arbitrary sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ satisfy the second-order (not necessarily linear) recurrence $x_{n+2}=f(n,x_{n+1}, x_n)$ and satisfy the conditions $a_1=b_1$ and $a_2=b_2$. Then $a_n=b_n$ for all $n\ge 1$.

**Proof:** This is automatically true for $n=1$ and $n=2$. Suppose that for all $k\le n+1$, we have $a_k=b_k$. We will show that $a_{k+2}=b_{k+2}$. This is obvious. For 
$$a_{k+2}=f(k,a_{k+1}, a_k)=f(k,b_{k+1},b_k)=b_{k+2}.$$

**Remark:** We produced an induction proof of the lemma, since an induction proof  was asked for. The lemma has not much to do with our particular sequences, and can be proved for more general recurrences that $x_{n+2}=f(n,x_{n+1}, x_n)$. Once the lemma has been proved, it can be applied to any (say second order) recurrence, if we have a reasonable conjecture as to the solution. All we need to do is plug in the proposed solution and check whether the recurrence holds.

Comment: Thanks for this, it was really informative . :)